# "She's at THE airport"

Tags: articles

In one English grammar book, in the Articles section, there are exercises for the student. There are four pictures and below each one of them, the student is required to finish a sentence.

Description of the first picture: A boy is sleeping in bed. There is an alarm on a nightstand, and a lamp. So, the student must finish a sentence below the picture. The sentence is: He's in ________. According to the book, the answer is: He's in bed. I understand that. It's a fixed expression and it's a way it is.

Description of the second picture: There are people sitting in front of a big screen. The sentence is: They're at ________- The answer is They're at the movies. I understand that.

Description of the third picture: There is a man behind bars who looks desperate. The sentence is: He's in __________. The answer is He's in prison.

Description of the fourth picture is: There is a woman who's walking towards an airplane. The sentence is: She's at __________. The answer is She's at THE AIRPORT. I DONT understand this sentence. Why can't it be She's at AN AIRPORT? I've heard both English and American people say AN airport and THE airport.

Answer (score 4):

1. It could absolutely be "an airport"; a shortcoming of many tests is to expect only one of several valid possibilities. If you answered "an" and the test is being graded by a human, I think you can absolutely argue that your answer should be counted as correct.
2. That said, there are some idiomatic usages about articles with some public facilities or destinations. We can often (counter-intuitively) use the definite article ("the") when talking about a type of place in the abstract rather than a specific one: *Teenagers like hanging out at **the** mall.* — *Why drive when you can take **the** subway?* — *Real friends are those who will drive you to **the** airport at 3 am.*
3. These can have regional variants that aren't easy to explain. In American English, if you're sick, you "have to go to **the** hospital." In the UK, though, you "have to go to hospital"—no article at all! Meanwhile, in both places, an arrested criminal is going "to prison" (no article).
4. I think what's going on with "the airport," though, is that often the definite article is used with public places of which there's only one in the region. You might go to "**the** courthouse," "**the** beach," or "**the airport**," and within a local region, everyone knows which one you mean.

Comment: I think the book got it wrong. There is no mentioning about the girl traveling somewhere something similar. It is just one sentence She's at ________________. So, No. 4 is not the answer. There is no word about the girl being at the nearest airport. No. 1 I also think my answer would be counted as correct. No. 2 and 3, I thought about that too. Articles are just too complicated for me as my native language doesn't have them. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Why would anyone go to an airport that isn't the nearest one to them?
The book is 100% right.

"She's at an airport." sounds like a sentence out of an English workbook. It's grammatically correct, but I can't think of any situation where you would use that over "...the airport". If you're telling someone an airport experience, it's in a specific location for reference (note I said "an airport" there and it sounds normal because it's hypothetical and not a specific airport). Even in cities with multiple airports, people favor "the" over "an".

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Well, the book's suggested answer isn't inappropriate. (But neither is WantToKnow's.) Yes, I think category 2 from my list is involved. You could add a picture of a little girl in a hospital room, and American speakers would answer "She's in the hospital," and British speakers, "She's in hospital." But both would also accept "She's in *a* hospital."

Comment: How is the book's suggestion of "the airport" not appropriate? An airport technically works, but it's not the most natural way. I'd favor their chosen answer for people who want to sound natural.
Also I don't think any of your examples in #2 are idiomatic. Those all just fall under your own category 4. "in hospital" is an idiomatic example.

Comment: @GetOff—this would be more likely in the context of general aviation rather than commercial airlines, but I could very easily imagine someone hanging up a phone and saying "That was my sister, she's at an airport in the middle-of-nowhere Nebraska."

Comment: I didn't say "an" is never appropriate lol. The phrase "middle-of-nowhere" conveys that the speaker and listener have no context, i.e. there is no specificity. That makes "an" appropriate. That's a very specific circumstance vs the general.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: In a region with multiple airports, you might go to a further-away one if it flies a specific route that your local airport doesn't, or if you have a strong preference for a particular airline that has a hub there.  I agree that most people would still call it "*the* airport" instead of "*an* airport", though.

Comment: In case 3. the context of the dropping of the article is a bit different.  It is done for places when there is an implied activity.  I'm not sure how much they actually differ regionally, but certainly between British and American English.  So if you say someone "went to prison" you are usually implying they went as an inmate rather than as a guard or visitor, etc...  When someone is "in hospital" it is as a patient (British) and "in University" or "in school" is as a student (American).

Comment: @dan04 I don't know what you want me to say. I said A is acceptable grammatically, but without further context, THE is much more preferred and more natural. I live in a city with 3 major airports. I've never once heard someone say, "I'm going to an airport". It just sounds unnatural by itself, which is why the book chose THE over A.